# How to optimize a program for performance С

Tags: c

I wrote a program that counts a certain series of numbers, and so the question can someone vkursy how you can optimize this program (in terms of speed) so that it works for 1 million iterations, for me personally, it hangs for 1 million iterations.
I am waiting for your suggestions

The program counts the next row - 1/!1 + 1/!4 + 1/!7 and so on, up to pc capabilities

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(float n){
    int r;
    for(r = 1;n>1; r*=(n--));
    return r;
}

int main(){
  int how =1000000;
  float res;
  int i = 1;
  while(how>0)
  {
     res+=(float)1/(float)fact(i);
     how--;
     i+=3;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A single precision float can only represent numbers up to around 1e38, so the larget factorial you can calculate is around 34!.

Comment: See also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int how =20;
    float res=1;
    int i = 2,k=1;

    while(i<=how)
    {
        k=k*(i)*(i+1)*(i+2);//First : 1*2*3*4
                            //Second: 4!*5*6*7
                            //third : 7!*8*9*10
                            //fourth : 10!*11*12*13
                            // ect .... 
        res=res+ (float)1/k;
        i+=3;
    }

    printf("\n%f\n",res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be correct if the type of `how` would be `unsigned long long`. With an `int` instead, the last values overflow the range and `res` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The first limitation is not the number of iterations but the size of the numbers you use in your algorithm. The limit of single precision float is already pointed in comments, but there is also the limit of the int k. Here are the values of k during the 7 first passes :

```
24
5040
3628800
1932053504
2004189184
109641728 //<=== smaller than the previous (modulo)
-522715136
```

You could use a more appropriate type, for instance a `uint64_t`, but this doesn't fix the problem :

```
24
5040
3628800
6227020800
20922789888000
121645100408832000
17196083355034583040
7034535277573963776 //<=== smaller than the previous (modulo)
```

As you can see, the gain is minimal (7 correct values instead of 5 before overflowing the limit).

So what you want to do is simply not possible with a so simple algorithm. Moreover I think you should try to imagine what is the value of the factorial of one million before doing anything else... For instance, here are the factorial of 10 and 100, as you can see the growing between the two is spectacular :

```
3628800
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

On its side, the factorial of one million has more than 5 millions digits (by comparison, the number of atoms in the universe takes 80 digits). You wouldn't have enough with 10 complete books just to write it...

Comment: Consider using [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/) for [bignum arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)